# Total reputation in StackOverflow over time

Tags: discussion, reputation, metrics, stack-exchange-history

At DevDays, Joel showed a graph of StackOverflow site visits per day over time.

I'm curious how the total reputation in the system has grown over time, and how that compares with the total number of (registered) users.  Does anyone know of such a graph?  I don't know if there are any significant changes to reputation allocation (bounties maybe) but it'd also be neat if the graph marked when such changes occurred.

Comment: It keeps going up.

Comment: Try though we might.

Comment: It would be interesting to see rep and rep/user over time. Probably pretty doable with the data dump.

Comment: @TheTXI: We might be able to level it off indefinitely if a few more idiots find meta.

Comment: +1 to counteract pointless down-vote/

Comment: @Noldorin: You are suppose to vote on your view of the question, not to counteract or sympathy vote.

Comment: Give it a few months and it'll be relatively simple to get a datapoint for each month in StackQL, as I'm planning to give access to as many historical datasets as I have space for.

Comment: @Noldorin: It's people like you who keep driving the rep curve upward.  This rep hyperinflation is getting out of control, which is why I advocate a return to the rep gold standard.

Comment: http://zimbabwe.stackexchange.com

Comment: Another interesting item would be to see the PMF of reputations over time.